# how to get response in retrofit while using rxAndroid?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm currently following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mtrax/rxandroid-2-with-retrofit-2-and-gson-3f08d4c2627d). While I've successfully adopted rxAndroid to avoid the `Exception` caused by recycled view, I'm losing the `Response` object from retrofit.

My original request was made by...

```
interface UserRepo {
    @GET("user")
    fun get(): Call<User>
}

// then call it by
userRepo.get().enqueue(callback)
```

where `callback` would have the `Response` object, but after converting the above to...

```
interface UserRepo {
    @GET("user")
    fun get(): Single<User>
}

// then call it by
mCompositeDisposable.add(userRepo.get()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                            { success -> 
                                // todo success 
                            },
                            { error ->
                                // todo error
                            }
                    )
            )
```

I basically don't have access to `Response` from callback. I do kinda need the status code. Any idea how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Single<T>`, have it return `Single<Response<T>>`.